# Finish an activity when user presses positive button on an associated dialogue

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want my activity, which shows a dialogue, to finish when a user clicks on the positive button of the dialogue. Is this possible. where do I place finish()?

Code that calls the dialogue:

```
if(name.equals("")) {

        DialogFragment newFragment = new NouserFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "makeprofile"); }
```

code for dialogue:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.nouseralert)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Editprofile.class);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.ignore, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Put finish()  on click event of positive button of alert dialog.

Comment: post your code, so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: @DipakKeshariya no. That will not work because finish() is only recognized under a activity class. 
I get this error if I do put finish() on click event.

`The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}` 

@Ramkiran sure.

Comment: @K_K Then Write YourActivityName.this.finish(); it will solve your problem.

Comment: @K_K Why are you open new activity on click of positive button?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya that too does not work. I get this: `No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope` Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038436/how-to-use-startactivityforresult-through-a-dialogfragment) is my actual problem. And closing the current activity seems like the only way to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I was able to finish the activity by putting `getActivity().finish()` under the `onClick()` of dialogue interface.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
public void showMessageAlert(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeScreen.this);

                builder.setTitle(ConfigClass.ALERT_TITLE);
                builder.setMessage(ConfigClass.MSG_ALERT);

                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("I Accept",   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        ActivityName.this.finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("I decline",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on click of positive button of the dialog call `dialog.dismiss();` then `finish();`

Comment: But it does not recognize finish() because it is not a Activity class.

Comment: @K_K so from where  you open the Dialouge?

Comment: @K_K you can use Activity as a Dialog, if there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

That's a Java problem with inner class visibility/scope. Inside the listener, `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` object and (luckily) it has no `finish()` method. To have it refer to the activity, either:

- use simply `finish()`, without any prefix, if the listener is defined inside the activity. This way Java will look for the nearest enclosing object which defines a method named `finish()`, and it will find the Activity's one
- use `YouActivity.this.finish()` to refer to the enclosing activity instance without any ambiguity (obviously this holds true if the listener is a (possibly anonymous) inner class of `YourActivity`
- Call `mActivity.finish()` on some instance of your activity if it's defined in another file altogether (and maybe you'll have to cast the `Context` object)

Usually listeners are defined as anonymous inner classes inside activities, so calling finish() unprefixed should be enough, but you may want to use the `A.this.finish()` form if there are name collisions